# Which Sitecore Nuget Package should I use?

Tags: nuget

If I am starting a basic Sitecore MVC project, which package(s) should I install?  The main `Sitecore` package seems like overkill.  For now I will just be creating some basic components, though some will probably need to use the Content Search APIs.

I have read the [doc page](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecore_public_nuget_packages_faq) and this [blog from Jeremy Davis](https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2016/09/05/the-official-sitecore-nuget-feed-is-here/), but I haven't found anything that identifies the best meta-packages to use for common taks.

Comment: Yeah the Sitecore it self will add refs you don't need but Kasaku's answer is specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the very least, you'll want the Sitecore.Kernel assembly which contains the core API and most of the utilty classes you will use when working with Sitecore:

`Sitecore.Kernel`

For working with MVC, grab the MVC package:

`Sitecore.Mvc`

If you are going to be using ContentSearch and will work with Lucene indexes, you can get:

`Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Lucene`

Each of these packages has a `.NoReferences` suffix variant which will get that single assembly and reference no other packages.

Answer (score 2):

There are few different types of NuGet packages available with Sitecore public NuGet. One type is, with all the references, which is the one you have mention. Other type is Individual dll Nuget packages.

If you want individual dlls, then you can use **.NoReference** dll NuGet Packages from Sitecore public Nuget source.

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum you would want `Sitecore.Kernel` and `Sitecore.Mvc`. This would give you enough to create basic components with MVC integration.